# svn2git - migrate trunk code to main branch instead of master in git

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

Using svn2git to migrate from SVN to git. While migrating, trunk code is migrated to 'master' branch in git. Instead I need to migrate trunk code to 'main' branch in git. Is that possible to customize default branch with svn2git?

Comment: Assuming this is the source code, then it seems like master are hardcoded: https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/blob/master/lib/svn2git/migration.rb#L340

Comment: If you can do the whole thing in one pass, just let the software use the name `master`, then rename it when the migration is finished. Branch names in Git have no underlying meaning and may be changed at any time without affecting anything (except human brains, if they remember the old name).